Print Plotly.js graph to PDF using React
I am using React with Typescript on my project. I also use plotly.js for plots. At a click of a button which I place below the plot, I would like to take a screenshot of the plot and then print it out on pdf. Plotly has built-in functionality to print an image of the plot and the documentation says I can use the Plotly.downloadImage function to download the image (not onto PDF yet) but I get errors when I use this. Please note the issue here is not downloading a pdf document but accessing the screenshot of the plotly graph.
This is basically my code: Expecting the same thing to happen when clicking on the built-in download image icon but I get an error instead.
import React, { useRef } from 'react';
import Plot from 'react-plotly.js';
import Plotly from 'plotly.js';

const PlotlyChart: React.FC = () => {
  const plotRef = useRef<Plotly.PlotlyHTMLElement | null>(null);

  const handleDownloadImage = () => {
    if (plotRef.current) {
      Plotly.downloadImage(plotRef.current, {
        format: 'png', // You can change this to 'jpeg', 'svg', 'webp', etc.
        filename: 'custom_plot_image',
        height: 600,
        width: 800,
      });
    }
  };

  const plotlyConfig: Partial<Plotly.Config> = {
    displayModeBar: true,
    toImageButtonOptions: {
      format: 'png',
      filename: 'custom_plot_image',
      height: 600,
      width: 800,
    },
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <Plot
        data={[
          {
            x: [1, 2, 3, 4],
            y: [10, 15, 13, 17],
            type: 'scatter',
            mode: 'lines+markers',
            marker: { color: 'red' },
          },
        ]}
        layout={{ width: 700, height: 500, title: 'A Fancy Plot' }}
        config={plotlyConfig}
        ref={plotRef}
      />
      <button onClick={handleDownloadImage}>Download Image</button>
    </div>
  );
};

export default PlotlyChart;

